# Is this grammatically correct? - I guess it is caused by many of the stones are overlapping with each other

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this grammatically correct?

> I guess it is caused by many of the stones are overlapping with each other.

I think **be caused by** should be followed by reasons, but I am not sure it could be a clause or only a phrase. And If it could be a clause, should I use **be** instead of **are** ? And finally, if yes, what's the name of this grammar?

> I guess it is caused by many of the stones being overlapping with each other.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

> I guess it is caused by many of the stones overlapping each other.

You don't need the "are" and you don't need the "being" and you don't need the "with".

Overlapping is a verb so you don't need the "are" or "being".